# Extracting certain word(s) after specific pattern, while excluding specified patterns. in R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

Using R, I want to extract the building, plaza or mansion names. The names are ahead of whether its specified a building ,mansion, plaza.
Here is an example

```
addresses<-c("big fake plaza, 12 this street,district, city", 
"Green mansion, district, city", 
 "Block 7 of orange building  district, city",
"98 main street block a blue plaza, city",
 "blue red mansion, 46 pearl street, city")
```

What I want to get is

```
"big fake" "Green" "orange" "blue" "blue red"
```

The code I currently using is

```
str_extract(addresses, "[[a-z]]*\\s*[[a-z]+]*\\s*(?=(building|mansion|plaza))")
```

Sometime the name is two words sometimes one. However because of the varied format, sometimes there is an 'a' or 'of' which is also getting extracted. How do I continue to extract the two word formats of the building name but exclude  the 'a' or 'of'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to optionally match a first word, ruling out some of the words that are not accepted using a negative lookahead.

```
\b(?:(?!of|a)[a-zA-Z]+\s+)?[a-zA-Z]+\b(?=\s+(?:building|mansion|plaza)\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!of|a)` Negative lookahead, assert not `of` or `a` directly to the right
  - `[a-zA-Z]+\s+` If the assertion is true, match 1+ times a char a-zA-Z followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `[a-zA-Z]+\b` Match 1+ times a char a-zA-Z and a word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:building|mansion|plaza)\b` Match one of the alternatives
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DADtQd/1)

```
addresses<-c("big fake plaza, 12 this street,district, city", 
"Green mansion, district, city", 
 "Block 7 of orange building  district, city",
"98 main street block a blue plaza, city",
 "blue red mansion, 46 pearl street, city")
 
str_extract(addresses, "\\b(?:(?!of|a)[a-zA-Z]+\\s+)?[a-zA-Z]+\\b(?=\\s+(?:building|mansion|plaza)\\b)")
```

Output

```
[1] "big fake" "Green"    "orange"   "blue"     "blue red"
```

**Note** that `[[a-z]]*`should be with single brackets `[a-z]*` if you optionally want to repeat the range a-z in the character class, and `[[a-z]+]*` should be `[a-z]+` if you want to repeat the range 1+ times in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really come up with a solution that can handle all of it in one regex.

Here's a two step process.

1. Extract one or two words before `(building|mansion|plaza)`
2. From the extracted words remove `(on|of|a)` from it.

```
vals <- stringr::str_match(addresses, "(\\w+?\\s?\\w+)\\s(building|mansion|plaza)")[, 2]
trimws(gsub('\\b(on|of|a)\\b', '', vals))

#[1] "big fake" "Green"    "orange"   "blue"     "blue red"
```